# Regex to match pattern "Double-Double;"

Tags: c#, regex

I have trouble finding a regex matching this pattern:

- A numeric (decimal separator can be `.` or `,`), followed by
- a dash `-`, followed by
- a numeric (decimal separator can be `.` or `,`), followed by
- a semi-column or a space character

This pattern can be repeated one or more time.

The following examples should match the regex:

```
1-2;
1-2;3-4;5-6;
1,0-2;
1.0-2;
1,0-2.0;
1-2 3-4;
1-2 3,00-4;5.0-6;
```

The following examples should not match the regex:

```
1-2
1 2;
1_2;
1-2;3-4
```

Comment: You are aware of the conditional operator (a|b) right?

Comment: @Peter I wasn't. It could help a lot :)

Comment: `1 2;` appears in both the list of items that should match and the list of items that shouldn't match.

Comment: @Utensil Again a mistake from me! I should read what I wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** updated based on moving of `1 2;` to non-match.

---

This should work:

```
@"^(\d+([,.]\d+)?-\d+([,.]\d+)?[ ;])+(?<=;)$"
```

Explanation

```
^              //Start of the string.
(              //Start of group to be repeated. You can also use (?=
\d+            //One or more digits.
([,.]\d+)?     //With an optional decimal
-              //Separated by a dash
\d+([,.]\d+)?  //Same as before.
[ ;]           //Terminated by a semi-colon or a space
)+             //One or more of these groups.
(?<=;)         //The last char before the end needs to be a semi-colon
$              //End of string.
```

Comment: Looks good, except I don't think space is an alternative to dash, looks like it can only be used in place of a semicolon.

Comment: You don't have to escape the . inside brackets

Comment: @IAbs Thanks, I always forget about that. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks that works. I updated my question after your answer so it does not quite answer it now, but I managed to adapt it: `@"^([0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?[-][0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?[ ;])+(?<=;)$"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@"^([\d.,]+-[\d.,]+[ ;])*[\d.,]+-[\d.,]+;$"
```

Note that `[\d.,]+` accepts some character sequences which wouldn't normally be considered valid "numeric" values such as `00..,.,`. You might want to find a better regular expression to match numeric values and substitute it into the regular expression.

Comment: +1 @Joey But this is a little better: `(0|[1-9]\d*)` otherwise, it won't accept `10`